# Data Bound ComboBox partially unclickable

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have some ComboBoxes set up like this:

```
    <ComboBox Name="CB_OS" Grid.Row="5" ItemsSource="{Binding OS_Sellection}" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="2" SelectionChanged="OSSelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Name}" IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

The ComboBox fills with ComboBoxItems correctly, but clicking on the text (Content) does not select the Item.  I must click elsewhere, where there is no text to actually change the selected item.

If I change it to this:

```
<ComboBox Name="CB_OS" Grid.Row="5" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="2" SelectionChanged="OSSelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="OOOOOOOOO"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="OOOOOOOOO"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="OOOOOOOOO"/>
</ComboBox>
```

it works fine.

OS_Selection contains only the following members:

```
private string name;
private bool isChecked;
private bool isSelected;
```

So my question is: How can I make the entire row (item) clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put a `ComboBoxItem` inside the `ComboBox.ItemTemplate`

Change this:

```
     <ComboBox Name="CB_OS" Grid.Row="5" ItemsSource="{Binding OS_Sellection}" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="2" SelectionChanged="OSSelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Name}" IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

for this:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="5" Margin="2"
          ItemsSource="{Binding OS_Sellection}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Also, WPF does not bind to `private fields`, only `public properties`.